# error when granting rights to server role

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working with sql server 2012 - I have created a Server Role - XXXX and I want to grant execute priviliges to this role on a stored procedure. I am using this command:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure] TO [XXXX]
```

However I get this error:

> Cannot find the user 'XXXX', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Any idea if my syntax is wrong or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try a database role instead of a server role.

Comment: Server roles are for admin privileges like backing up, administering stuff etc - not for access to database objects.... see the [standard, built-in server roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx) for an idea of what kind of privileges these are for!